# Matching based on various types and object attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, object, attributes

I have a list of objects from which I'm trying to filter objects based on selected criteria returning a list of matches. The attributes are strings, integers, floats and objects. The problem I have is trying to filter based on object attributes, I'd like to do this:

> findOrder(d, signal='CO', contract.symbol=1)

I cannot simply compare the objects by themselves as I only need to match based on the most important attributes and the attributes differ on various objects.

Thus far I can successfully flatten the objects into a dict and then do a simple dictionary comparison. Yet this is very ugly and I suspect slow:

> findOrder(d, signal='CO', contractSymbol=1)

```
class emptyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.Symbol = a
        self.Order = b
s = emptyObj(a=1, b=2)

class toObj(object):
    def __init__(self, d): [setattr(self, a, b) for a, b in d.items()]

def findOrder(d, **kwargs):
    def flatten(di):
        ls = []
        for o in di:
            e = {}
            for k, v in o.__dict__.items():
                if isinstance(v, (int, float, str, tuple, list, dict)):
                    e[k] = v
                else:
                    for attr, val in v.__dict__.items(): e[str(k)+str(attr)] = val
            ls.append(e)
        return ls

    g = flatten(d)
    l = [k for k in g if kwargs.items() <= k.items()]
    if l: return l

d = [toObj({'id':1250, 'signal': 'CO', 'contract': s}),
     toObj({'id':1252, 'signal': 'LO', 'contract': s})]

print(findOrder(d, signal='CO'))
```

Is there a more optimal and straightforward way to do this?

Comment: why are your variables named `g` `d` `l` `ls` `a` `b` ?

Comment: Looks cleaner and that's what I have used. Is there a collision?

Comment: It's pretty hard to read your code because your variable names aren't self-documenting.

Comment: It's super hard to understand because I don't have your input list and it does not seem worth it to focus really hard to remember what `g` was after I saw `d` `l` `ls` `a` and `b` variables. Opposite of clean actually

Comment: There is no input list. Everything is in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re trying to filter objects by attribute, use either `filter` or a list comprehension with a function that checks attributes:

```
def check_attrs(**kw):
    def wrapper(obj):
        return all(getattr(obj, k) == v for k, v in kw.items())
    return wrapper
```

Then you filter the objects:

```
filtered = list(filter(check_attrs(signal='CO'), objects))
```

Or...

```
filtered = [obj for obj in objects
            if check_attrs(signal='CO')(obj)]
```

Comment: How would I go about it when trying to filter by contract.Symbol or contract.Order? I'm getting "keyword can't be an expression".